# In PhoneGap Android C2DM BroadcastReceiver, how to call sendJavascript()

Tags: android, cordova, android-c2dm

I want to pass received message from C2DM to WebView javaScript function.
I think the code is below...

```
public class C2DMReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  ....

  private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
  {        
     String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");

     this.ctx.sendJavascript("myJavascriptFunction(" + msg +")");

  }
```

}

But I don't know How exactly to pass it. Please.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your ctx is an instance of com.phonegap.api.Plugin you should try

```
this.ctx.sendJavascript("javascript:myJavascriptFunction(" + msg +")");
```